# Music on Mac OS: hide huge playlist title area, when viewing playlist “as Songs”?

Tags: itunes, music.app, playlist

In the Mac OS Music app (formerly iTunes), when viewing a playlist or smart playlist “as Songs”, there’s a huge playlist title/header area.  **Is there any way to hide or shrink this header area?**  At least in my usage, it’s an obnoxious waste of space: it takes up about 1/3 of my whole screen height to very little purpose, and leaves the column browser and playlist contents very cramped (see screenshot).  When viewing “as Playlist”, you can scroll this header area up offscreen, but when viewing “as Songs” (which I prefer, as a fan of the column browser) and in most other views, it stays fixed.

[image: Screenshot showing huge header area]

I’m currently using Big Sur 11.6, using Music 1.1.6.)

Comment: I would like this, too. I can’t believe how stupidly rigid it is! I’ve found no way to do so, yet.

Comment: 5 upvotes in a year, I think we are the exception :(

Comment: Oh my God. I can't believe people put up with this. I haven't used the music app in awhile, clearly.